# In Google Sheets, can you repeatedly autofill until next non-blank cell all at once?

Tags: google-sheets

Basically, what I want to do is fill all of the blank cell in a column with the value of the last  non-blank cells. For example:

[image: From this] ---------> [image: to this.]

I was wondering if there was a way to do this without having to do the auto-fill individually for each set of cells with the same value, as I have a sheet that's thousands of entries long.

Answer (score 2):

To do this with formula:

**1.)** In a completely blank column, enter the following formula in the top cell (e.g., B1):

`=ArrayFormula(VLOOKUP(ROW(A:A),FILTER({ROW(A:A),A:A},A:A<>""),2,TRUE))`

This will fill the array.

**2.)** Click the letter at the top of the output column to select the entire column.

**3.)** Hit `Ctrl-C` to copy the entire contents of that column to clipboard.

**4.)** Click the `A` at the top of Column A to select the entire original column.

**5.)** Click `Ctrl-Alt-V` ("Paste Special"). A small clipboard icon will appear lower right of the visible screen area. Click it and choose `Paste values only`.

**6.)** Click the letter at the top of the formula column to select that entire column again and then click the `Delete` key to delete the formula and its results from that column, returning it to its original blank state.

The entire process should take about 10 seconds.